# FreeBSD GELI Encrypted Disk Capacity vs Unencrypted

Tags: freebsd, disk-encryption

I encrypt my external backup devices with AES256 using GELI on FreeBSD 11. I have recently changed the disks to 240GB SSDs whereby only half the capacity is usable which is causing the backup to fail.

- Windows 10; SSD shows 232GB
- FreeBSD 11; SSD shows 207GB

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da0 bs=1M count=10
  gpart add -t freebsd /dev/da0
  newfs /dev/da0 >& /dev/null
  mount /dev/da0 /mnt/backup
  df -g
  /dev/da0   225  0  207  0%  /bk/disk
  ```
- FreeBSD 11; SSD shows 116GB

  ```
  da0.eli created
  da0.elis1 added
  =>       40  244198504  da0.eli  GPT  (116G)
           40  244198504        1  freebsd  (116G)
  /dev/da0.elis1   112  0  103  0%  /bk/disk
  ```

Is this expected or is it related to sector sizes?

Comment: I don't know specific details of FreeBSD, but this looks strange. Encryption is usually designed to have just a constant overhead, or a small factor overhead. Factor 2 is quite much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verification option -ahmac/sha256 requires 11% according to the man page.
The problem was having verification enabled without setting the default sector size specified requiring 50%. i.e. specify -s4096 with -ahmac/sha256

```
# geli init -l256 -eaes -ahmac/sha256 -J /root/da0.txt -B /root/da0.eli -K /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli attach -k /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli list
1. Name: da0.eli
   Mediasize: 125029674496 (116G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
Consumers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 250059350016 (233G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r1w1e1

# geli init -l256 -eaes -J /root/da0.txt -B /root/da0.eli -K /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli attach -k /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli list
1. Name: da0.eli
   Mediasize: 250059349504 (233G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
Consumers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 250059350016 (233G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r1w1e1

# geli init -s4096 -l256 -eaes -ahmac/sha256 -J /root/da0.txt -B /root/da0.eli -K /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli attach -k /root/da0.key /dev/da0
# geli list
1. Name: da0.eli
   Mediasize: 222274973696 (207G)
   Sectorsize: 4096
   Mode: r0w0e0
Consumers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 250059350016 (233G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r1w1e1
```